# excel vba select target sheet with range

Tags: excel, vba

This script only select the current sheets

```
Sheets(Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 2).Text).Visible = True
```

i tried

```
Sheets("name).Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 2).Text.Visible = True
```

is not work, how to select the target sheet?

thanks

Comment: Your code does not actually`Select` anything. Also note syntax/typo error in the second line of code.  What exactly are you trying to do, please describe in more detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheets("name_of_sheet").Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 2).Text.Visible = True
```

Works for me. Are you missing the 2nd `"` in `Sheets("name)` or was it a typo in this question?